# rx macro and eager macro-expansion failure in Emacs

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp

```
(defun my-blah (str)
  (rx (+ (eval (substring str 1)))))
```

Evaluation of that code puts the following message in the Messages buffer:

```
Eager macro-expansion failure: (void-variable str)
```

What does it mean and is it something to worry about?

The function seems to work fine. On the other hand, evaluation of the following code doesn't generate such a message:

```
(defvar my-str "oink")
(rx (+ (eval (substring my-str 1))))
```

---

Appendix: alternative ways to define the function without generating such messages

```
(defun my-nah (str)
  (rx-to-string `(+ ,(substring str 1))))

(defun my-llama (str)
  (eval `(rx (+ ,(substring str 1)))))
```

Comment: Works, perfectly fine on emacs 24.3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rx` is a macro, which implies that it can be expanded pretty much at any time before actually evaluating the code.  Typically, it means it will be expanded during compilation.  Compilation happens before `str` is known, so the expansion of `rx` cannot depend on the value of `str`.

If you test it without compiling it, then macroexpansion happens late (just before/during evaluation) so the problem is hidden (tho if you use `lexical-binding` the problem will re-appear because the `eval` will not have access to the lexical context in which `str` is defined).

Eager macroexpansion (new in 24.4), is used to expand macros when *loading* a non-compiled file, which provides a macro-expansion behavior similar to the one for compiled code.  For backward-compatibility, when an error occurs during eager macro-expansion, Emacs falls back on expanding macros late (after emitting the warning you saw).

Comment: Stefan, isn't it in 24.3, instead of 24.4?  I see the same error while using "GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.8.4)\n of 2013-09-27 on trouble, modified by Debian"

Comment: Oops, sorry, yes indeed, eager macroexpansion was introduced in 24.3.  Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to easily test your rx expressions, use this :

```
(defun test-rx (test-file test-reg)

  (if (get-buffer (setq test-buffer "RX"))
      (kill-buffer test-buffer))

  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents-literally test-file)
    (goto-char (point-min))

    (while
        (re-search-forward test-reg nil t)
      (when (match-string 0)
        (let ((one (match-string 1))
              (two (match-string 2)))
          (if one
              (progn
                (pop-to-buffer test-buffer)
                (goto-char (point-max))
                (insert (format "Found %s and possibly %s" one two)))))))))

(defun test-rx-now (file)
  "plop"
  (interactive
   (let (file)
     (setq file (read-file-name "File to search: "))
     (list file)))

  (test-rx file
           (rx
            "$(function"
            (*? anything)
            (or "'" "\"")
            (group
             (* (not (any "'" "\"")))
             ".php"
             )
            (or "'" "\"")
            (*? anything)
            "})"
            )))
```